# Inner product of two time-like vectors?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, vectors

Given two different time-like vectors $V,W$, can we say that $g(V,W)\leq0$ for any metric $g$ with the $(-, +, +, +)$ signature?  Cause I've seen written that if I'm outside the ergosphere the combination
$$E=-g(∂_{t},p)$$
is positive, where $p$ is the four momenta of an incoming particle. I don't know how to prove it. It's also written because both vectors are time-like, that's why I asked that question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What asserted, **with the strong inequality $>$**, is true provided the two vectors are timelike **and** stay in the same half of the light cone, as is in the case your consider. Here is the proof.

Fix an arbitrary orthonormal basis of the tangent space at the considered point of the spacetime. Suppose that the zeroth element of that basis is the temporal one so that the remaining ones are spatial. I denote with an arrow $\vec{U}$ the set of $n-1$ spatial components of a vector $U$.

If the signature is $-,+....+$, a vector $U$ is timelike if and only if  $(U^0)^2 > \vec{U}^2$. Therefore, if also $V$ is,
$$(U^0V^0)^2> \vec{U}^2\vec{V}^2\geq (\vec{V}\cdot \vec{U})^2$$
where I used  the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. All that implies
$$(U^0V^0)^2>(\vec{V}\cdot \vec{U})^2\:.$$
In summary $-g(U,V)$ cannot vanish and has the same sign as $U^0V^0$. The two vectors stay in the same half of the lightcone if and only if  the sign is positive, hence the statement is true.

Notice that, by continuity, as the timelike vectors are dense in the set of causal ones, the statement, **with** $\geq$, is true also if the two vectors are causal and in the same half of the light cone. That is the case when considering a massless particle for instance.

Comment: Last paragraph “as the timelike vectors are dense in the set of lightlike ones”, I’d replace lightlike with causal, since it seems weird to describe density when it’s not even a subset. Also for OP’s knowledge, we can generalize this just a tiny bit more and prove that given two (non-zero) causal vectors in the same half-cone, their inner product is $\leq 0$, with equality if and only if the two vectors are null and one is a (necessarily positive, since we’re in the same half-cone) scalar multiple of the other.

Comment: Alternatively, the light like vectors are accumulation points of timelike ones. I changed the text. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed!

Answer (score 4):

in the (-, +, +, +) signature, yes, any two future-pointing timelike vectors will have a negative inner product.  Just take it from the 2D special relativity thing where all unit timelike vectors, as one typically parametrizes worldline vectors of observers, can be taken as:

$$v = (\cosh \psi, \sinh \psi)$$

for some hyperbolic angle $\psi$.  Then, the inner product of two vectors is $ \sinh \psi_{1} \sinh \psi_{2} -\cosh \psi_{1} \cosh \psi_{2}$, which is always less than zero because $\cosh$ is always bigger than $\sinh$.  Generalizing to the case of non-unit vectors is trivial because one is always free to just multiply by the norm that you wish the new vector to have, and $A\cosh \psi$ is always greater than $A \sinh \psi$ for all $A > 0$

Your confusion about the Kerr metric in the ergosphere arises from the fact that $\partial_{t}$ is no longer a timelike vector inside of the ergosphere even though it has the label $t$.  The frame dragging of the black hole creates an effect that makes it impossible to be stationary relative to infinity, and so the timelike evolution vector has to include a $\partial_{\phi}$ component.

Comment: Note that $\partial_{t}$ being spacelike is also a feature of the Schwarzschild interior.  The proper time inside the Schwarzschild horizon is ticked off by the $r$ coordinate, which is why reaching the singularity is inevitable.  (and also why the Schwarzschild horizon is spacelike --$r = 0$ is a point in time, not a spatial location)

Comment: The statement is not true as written. You need to add the extra hypothesis that both timelike vectors lie in the same half-cone (i.e either they’re both future-oriented or both past-oriented). This is of course the case in OP’s situation since $\partial_t$ defines the time-orientation and by definition particles have future-directed tangent vectors (and hence the momentum being a positive multiple, is also future-directed).

Comment: Likewise, *“Just take it from the 2D special relativity thing where all timelike vectors can be taken as: $v = (\cosh \psi, \sinh \psi)$ for some hyperbolic angle $\psi$”*. Also not true. These timelike vectors have “unit norm”, and even then, you only took into account those with positive $t$-component (i.e future-directed in Minkowski).

Comment: @peek-a-boo: I will add the explanations to the answer, but seriously, in >95% of applications, one only considers unit norm future-pointing timelike vectors, and you very very well know it.

Comment: Yes of course it’s common practice since we can rescale as we like, but I am of the opinion that some words/phrases shouldn’t be thrown around lightly such as “for all/every”, since as a student it’s definitely confusing at first.